# Как настроить высоту Google Карты?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

https://uzinouzi.github.io/perila/

В самом низу — карта от Google. Как сделать так что бы она была по высоте как фиолетовый блок? На `height 100%` никак не реагирует.

P.S. На адаптив не смотрите, я его пока не делал. :)

Comment: Задать `.map .map_place` либо `section.map` жестко фиксированную высоту в пикселях.

Comment: А вариантов с относительными величинами нет? Проблем с адаптивом в дальнейшем не может возникнуть?

Comment: Карты строятся на js, который должен знать, сколько у него места будет, а так 100% от чего? Самый простой вариант - дать фикс высоту `secrtion.map`, тогда карта встанет на 100%. При адаптиве все блоки ужимаются, меняются местами, поэтому в вашем случае она вообще под форму уедет, тогда ей (карте) зададите меньшую высоту (200 за глаза).

Comment: И да, не используйте iframe по возможности, для этого есть API у любой из карт

Comment: можно при загрузке карты с помощью js посчитать высоту фиолетового блока и присвоить фикс высоту карте

Answer (score 0):

```css
section.map.clearfix{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

И убрать `width` у `.form_place` и `.map_place`